# React js - detect change orientation on mobile

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html, dom-events

I want to detect orientation change on mobile and dynamically set header height with clientHeight. I see that I have window.orientation property but how to check when orientation of device is changed ? I want to write some code whenever orientation is changed. I was trying to check orientation with resize event but this is not how I want to do this.

```
resize = () => {
    console.log(window.orientation);
    const header = document.querySelector('header');
    let height = document.documentElement.clientHeight + 'px';
    header.style.height = height;
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.resize);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.resize);
  }
```

**EDIT**

How to check **ORIENTATION** change event not **RESIZE** event in js. When I change orientation on mobile I want to change height on header, only on orientation change. On resize event header's height is changed whenever menu on browser is showing or hiding.

Comment: What is the problem with this approach? "but this is not how I want to do this" does not give us enough information as to why you don't want to use this

Comment: Event is resize, but I want to only change height on change orientation

Comment: jQuery has this event, but how to use this in vanilla js or react ?? https://api.jquerymobile.com/orientationchange/

Comment: Have you tried looking at the `window.screen` object and detecting that the `availWidth` has changed? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen

Comment: Why duplicate?? I don't want to check width of my screen. I want to check orientation. When orientation is changed on mobile I want to set height to header but when I call this on resize every time browser menu show and hide it's changing my headers height... That's not resize event

Comment: There's an answer there that shows you how to use screen width to detect that the resize is on the screen. See https://davidwalsh.name/orientation-change You can also use `window.matchMedia("(orientation: landscape)")` to know if you are in landscape

Comment: Yes, this matchMedia it is what I was looking for :) Thank you !!